# ASP.Net ApiController how replace Controller.Response

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-headers, asp.net-web-api2, export-to-csv, asp.net-apicontroller

I have a method, that was written in ASP.net MVC **Controller**:

```
[HttpGet]
        public void ExportClientsListToCSV()
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Exported_Contacts.csv");
            Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
            Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
            Response.BinaryWrite(Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            sw.WriteLine("\"FullName\",\"Position\",\"BranchOffice\",\"PrivateEmail\"");
            foreach (var line in db.Persons)
            {
                sw.WriteLine("\"{0}\",\"{1}\",\"{2}\",\"{3}\"",
                                           line.FullName,
                                           line.Position,
                                           line.BranchOffice,
                                           line.PrivateEmail);
            }
            Response.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.End();
        }
```

I want to use it in **ApiController**, but in **ApiController** there is no member **Response**. How can I replace it? There is **HttpResponseMessage**, but I can't do the same thing with it.
Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should be equivalent:

```
var sw = new StringWriter();
sw.WriteLine("\"FullName\",\"Position\",\"BranchOffice\",\"PrivateEmail\"");
foreach (var line in db.Persons)
{
    sw.WriteLine("\"{0}\",\"{1}\",\"{2}\",\"{3}\"",
        line.FullName,
        line.Position,
        line.BranchOffice,
        line.PrivateEmail);
}

return new HttpResponseMessage
{
    Content = new StringContent(sw.ToString(), Encoding.Unicode)
    {
        Headers =
        {
            ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/csv"),
            ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = "Exported_Contacts.csv"
            }
        }
    },
    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
};
```